# Самый быстрый способ найти соседей в окрестности элемента в массиве

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, дерево

Для заданного массива вещественных чисел необходимо для каждого элемента определить количество элементов которые меньше данного не более чем на 0,5.

Например:

Дан массив:

```
[0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
```

Массив который необходимо получить:

```
[0,   0,   1,   2,    3,   0,   1]
```

Какой алгоритм и структуру данных лучше использовать для решения данной задачи, чтобы добиться максимальной скорости?

Важно чтобы это работало меньше минуты на массиве в 1000000 вещественных чисел.

Я пытался использовать просто встроенный выбор элементов с помощью numpy:

```
def find_nearest(X):
    mas=[]
    for el in X:
        mas.appen(len(X[(X>(el-0.5)) & (X<el)]))
    return mas
~~~

А так же пытался использовать `BallTree`:

    tree2 = BallTree(X, leaf_size=X.shape[0], metric=distance) 
    mas=tree2.query_radius(X, r=0.5, count_only = True)
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

Просто просканировать (сортированный) список/массив в обратном направлении. Время линейное

```
#A = [0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
#A = [0.25, 0.7, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
A = [0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 1.5, 1.7]
B = [0] * len(A)
idx = len(A) - 1
for i in range(len(A) - 1, 0, -1):
     while idx >= 0 and A[i] - A[idx] < 0.5:
         idx -= 1
     B[i] = i - idx - 1
print(B)
```

Comment: Выходит [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1], надо с левым краем что-то делать

Comment: Первый элемент всегда ноль, можно инициализировать B нулями. Но у вас принципиальная ошибка - `idx` надо инициализировать каждую операцию как `i-1`, а то у вас он уезжает. Поэтому и время линейное выходит. А на самом деле нет.

Comment: Да, про индекс была другая ошибка, теперь вроде верно )

Comment: @CrazyElf Почему же не слушаю.. Есть время - правлю. С движением idx только влево - принципиальный момент. Вроде поправил. И охота раскапывать раритеты ? ;)

Comment: Блин, только сейчас заметил, что вопрос то старый )))  Просто его поправили недавно. А теперь проверьте на таком массиве [0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7] ;)

Comment: Он не сортированный

Comment: Тьфу блин, ну [0, 0.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.7] тогда. Смысл в том, что индекс уезжает и не возвращается

Comment: [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2]  - правильно. Зачем же ему возвращаться, если в сортированном массиве не может интервал меньших чисел для левого элементы кончаться правее, чем такой же интервал для правого?

Comment: Кажется, я запутался. Да, вы правы, я не совсем правильно понял алгоритм.

Comment: Ну зато ошибки отловили.

Comment: Быстро прям работает. С Numba можно ещё раз в 10 ускорить, но уже и так в требования укладывается.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [61]: x = np.subtract.outer(a, a)

In [62]: ((x > 0) & (x < 0.5)).sum(axis=1)
Out[62]: array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1])
```

Comment: Красивое решение, но на 10^6 элементах матрица будет 10^12 и ОЗУ просто не хватит ))